# Does React Native support Apple's M1 macbook pro?

Tags: react-native

Can ios apps be compiled on the new M1 chipset?
Is there any schedule for official support?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes.

The latest version of XCode (version 12) is compiled as a universal app. This means that it runs on both Intel-based and Mac Sillicon machines natively. From Apple's [website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/):

> Xcode 12 is built as a Universal app that runs 100% natively on Intel-based CPUs and Apple Silicon for great performance and a snappy interface.* It also includes a unified macOS SDK that includes all the frameworks, compilers, debuggers, and other tools you need to build apps that run natively on Apple Silicon and the Intel x86_64 CPU.

This means that you should be able to compile iOS with the latest version of XCode without a problem. It would be kind of crazy for Apple to release professional hardware (MacBook Pro) without this capability.

Keep in mind that a number of third party applications may not work well on the ARM machines yet. VSCode is not currently supported on M1 devices (although Microsoft have said that it's coming). VSCode is an Electron based app which currently can't be emulated with Apple's Rosetta II platform. You might not use VSCode, but keep in mind that any Electron based apps that you use may not work straight away.

If you exclusively use XCode and don't critically rely on any third-party apps you should be ok.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you tagged your post for react-native. Information is pretty slim for compatibility at the moment, so I would be cautious. If you need a Macbook Pro to do commercial work or school projects **right now** then you run the risk of things not working as intended. The M1 MacBooks will undoubtedly support everything that you need as a developer in the future and they're particularly great candidates for iOS development because of the parallels made possible by the shared ARM architecture.

If you're relying on a new machine to get work done right now, going with an Intel-based machine is probably the best option. For reference, I recently got an Intel-based 16" MacBook Pro with work because I need to get things done right now without any issues. The commercial value far outweighs the potential benefits that an M1 machine might bring in a year or two. If you're ok with running into some issues over the next few months, I'm sure that the M1 machines will provide plenty of value for years ahead.

Answer (score 3):

While there are problems that do not allow compiling the application.

brew and cocoapods are installed in the console with rosetta enabled.

pod install / update fails because flipper and some parts of RN are not supported by the platform

if you use expo - without cli then everything is ok

updates: now cli working (after update all - homebrew, cocoapods and other to last version)

[image]

Comment: Any updates for 2021? Is m1 support more widespread now?

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, iOS app only compiles on Mac os, so it should work with whatever macOS uses.